# maven 3 - Why is my compiler plugin out of date?

Tags: maven-3, maven-plugin

I downloaded the latest version of Maven from their site and am using it in Eclipse. But it seems my maven-compiler-plugin is out of date ie. version 3.1 while according to [this](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/) page the most recent version is 3.3. **First of all if I am using the latest version of maven why do I have to use an outdated plugin ?** **Secondly why is it out of date ?** I looked up the Super-POM and nothing about the compiler plugin was referenced there.

Comment: Your question doesn't really concern programmation, you might want to search for another SE to find answers.

Comment: @Peut22 Can this question be migrated over there ? Which SE are you referring to ?